# Recursively apply generic function to variadic tuple in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I come from a C++ background and am used to variadic templates which seem to be very similar to variadic tuples in Typescript. In broad strokes I am trying to apply a generic function over a variadic tuple, and I can't figure out the right way to write the types or the implementation to satisfy the compiler.

Here is an example (that you can also play with on https://playcode.io/1055590)

```js
import React, { createContext } from 'react';

function contextFunction<T>(context: React.Context<T>): void {}

// just do a foreach
function mapper<AllContexts extends React.Context<unknown>[]>(
  ...contexts: [...AllContexts]
): void {
  contexts.forEach(context => contextFunction(context));
}

// Try to "peel off" the head of the variadic tuple
// to get the concrete type for each element.
function mapper2<T, AllContexts extends React.Context<unknown>[]>(
  head: React.Context<T>,
  ...rest: [...AllContexts]
): void {
  contextFunction(head);
  if (rest.length) {
    const [restHead, ...restRest] = rest;
    mapper2(restHead, ...restRest);
  }
}

interface MyContext {
  x: number;
  y: string;
}

const exampleContext = createContext<MyContext>({ x: 42, y: 'hello' });

function example() {
  // here I used only one type of context, but imagine many different ones
  mapper(exampleContext); // error
  mapper2(exampleContext, exampleContext, exampleContext); // error
}
```

Typescript complains

```
Argument of type 'Context<MyContext>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Context<unknown>': 
  Types of property 'Provider' are incompatible: 
    Type 'Provider<MyContext>' is not assignable to type 'Provider<unknown>': 
      Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible: 
        Type 'ProviderProps<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'ProviderProps<MyContext>'.
```

The issue is specifying variadic tuples leads to `AllContexts extends React.Context<unknown>[]`, and `React.Context` doesn't like being assigned to `React.Context<unknown>`.

I want to make Typescript recursively peel off the types from the tuple, so at each step the exact concrete type is known. So no `unknown` business. Is there a way to make sure the most specific type is known for every entry of the tuple when iterating over it?

Comment: Why not this? https://tsplay.dev/w1Avyw

Comment: @vera. Hey, thanks for looking. I realized my question as stated was too simple, and didn't actually show the full problem I had in my code. I have modified my question and added a playcode.io link to a minimal example, where your suggestion doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky one. TS is able to infer types in variadic tuples, however it struggles when you use wrappers. For instance, when you use `AllContexts extends React.Context<unknown>[]` and then `[...AllContext]` it wont work. You need to infer first level type. I mean, you need to infer context shape `T` in `React.Context<T>`. `React.Context` hese is a wrapper and should be applied only at the end of inference.

First of all you need to infer `Obj`:

```js
function mapper<Obj>(
  contexts: React.Context<Obj>
): void {}

const first = createContext({ x: 42, y: "hello" });

mapper(first)
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NneGVw)

Now, when you hover on `mapper` you will get an infered value of context shape.

With variadic tuples approach is very similar. You still have to infer context shape and apply `React.Context` at the and and not on the beginning.

```js
import React, { createContext } from "react";

function contextFunction<T>(context: React.Context<T>): void {}

type Wrapper<List extends unknown[]> = {
  [Prop in keyof List]: React.Context<List[Prop]>;
};

function mapper<Obj, List extends Obj[]>(
  ...contexts: [...Wrapper<List>]
): void {
  contexts.forEach((context) => contextFunction(context));
}

const first = createContext({ x: 42, y: "hello" });
const second = createContext({ user: { name: "John" } });
const third = createContext({ data: [1, 2, 3] });

function example() {
  // here I used only one type of context, but imagine many different ones
  mapper(first); // ok
  mapper(first, second, third); // ok
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wyl0Am)

Works as expected.

`List extends Obj[]` infers an array of context shapes without `React.Context` wrapper. Then, `Wrapper` utility type iterates through each element of infered array and applies `React.Context` to the item

If you are interested in type inference on function arguments in typescript you can check my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)

---

UPDATE

Btw, if you use `any` in `React.Context<any>`, all provided contexts will be infered as expected:

```js
import React, { createContext } from 'react';

const mapper = <AllContexts extends React.Context<any>[]>(
    ...contexts: [...AllContexts]
) => { }

const exampleContext = createContext({ x: 42, y: 'hello' });
const exampleContext2 = createContext({ a: 1 });

mapper(exampleContext, exampleContext2); // ok
```

Comment: Thank you! What's interesting to me (and very different from C++ for example) is that `Obj` in the second example is not one type. It acts as a standin for all the `T` that appear in the list of `ReactContext<T>`. It is strange to me that it is a single parameter when really it's more like a "superposition" of all the Ts. Is there a name for this kind of type parameter?

Comment: @AlexanderKondratskiy I dont have C++ backround. It is just how inference on function arguments works. You can use several generics to infer function arguments